# Who is the composer of the Net Yaroze default music tracks, as featured in Team Fatal's "Terra Incognita"?

Tags: game-music-identification, terra-incognita

[*Terra Incognita*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSLcscq0Pmo) is a 3D action adventure game for the Sony PlayStation by Team Fatal. It's a Net Yaroze game, but it was published as a covermount game on Official UK PlayStation Magazine Issue 31's demo disc (Disc 14) (April 1998) (also known as *Euro Demo 31*).

Team Fatal consisted of:

- Mitsuru Kamiyama (Programmer)
- Shintaro Tajima (Graphic Designer)
- Kunikatsu Tachi (3D Designer)

However, there is no composer listed for, or credited in, the game despite the catchy upbeat soundtrack. This is because the game uses the sample music tracks `GOGO.SEQ` and `MUSI.SEQ` directly copied from the Net Yaroze SDK. The back of the *User's Guide* credits the Net Yaroze to SCEI, but I can't find any direct composer credit for these two music tracks; there's no listing of the staff involved in the *User's Guide*, only a generic reference to 'The Yaroze Team'. There's no metadata in `GOGO.SEQ` that I can easily see, though it might be written in a Japanese encoding that no program I have has managed to detect.

**Who composed `GOGO.SEQ`?**